# Deploying Java Web Project to Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm currently studying Java and have developed a Java Application which I want to host on Google App Engine but when I run it and select as WAR directory my WebRoot directory I get an error "GWT compilation failed" and it asks to add an entry but there is nothing to add. Could anyone help me. Here is the structure of my application:
[structure http://s13.postimage.org/777suvr53/project.jpg](http://s13.postimage.org/777suvr53/project.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GWT project, you must have entrypoint class and *.gwt.xml file. So, when you compile your application, GWT will try to find gwt.xml file first and then GWT will look entrypoint entry in gwt.xml.

You will not able to compile your jsp-servlet project with GWT. Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Could you please explain me or give example how should I create this file. Thanks.

Comment: Please follow below link, which guide how can you develop application with GWT.

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/


In GWT application, jsp pages might not be allowed.